# Android - Send parameters from parent activity to fragments continuously

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I developed an android applicaion with acion bar that has 3 tabs with 3 difrrent fragments and I tried to pass a parameter from parent activity to fragments, I used the solution given in  [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620711/how-to-pass-data-from-activity-to-fragment) qusetion and every thing is right, the only problem is that, now the activity sends this parameter to fragments just once at the start f applicaion, I need to get this parameter each time the user select the tabs, I think I should do this opration on `onTabSelected` method but have no idea how to do that, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this !!

```
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                        // Pass the position on tab click to ViewPager
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                        Log.d("tab selected",""+tab.getPosition());
                                    if(tab.getPosition==0)
                                 {
                                     Fragment fragA=new FrgmentA();
                                     fragA.getData("data");
                                 }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d("tab Unselected",""+tab.getPosition());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d("tab Reselected",""+tab.getPosition());
                    }
                };

                // Create first Tab
                tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Profile").setTabListener(tabListener);
                mActionBar.addTab(tab);

                // Create second Tab
                tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Picture").setTabListener(tabListener);
                mActionBar.addTab(tab);

                // Create third Tab
                tab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Help").setTabListener(tabListener);
                mActionBar.addTab(tab);




  FragmentA extends Fragment{

           public FragmentA(){            
          }
          @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);


        return view;
    }
    public void getData(String s)
{   // your implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: this code makes tabs and do swip between them, so how to pass a parameter from here to fragments?

Answer (score 0):

hey please pass the value when the fragment instance is created ,please take a look on below codes
I just passwed an list once the fragment is loaded via viewpager

> 

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, List<AccountDetail> listAc) {
        Homepage.ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new Homepage.ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new AllFragment("", listAc), "All");
        adapter.addFrag(new AllFragment("1", listAc), "Credit");
        adapter.addFrag(new AllFragment("2", listAc), "Debit");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

And then write a constructor in your fragment be like this

```
 public AFragment(String text, List<AccountDetail> manufactist) {
        mText = text;
        manufactureListAcoonut = manufactist;
    }
```